# R error in leaps regsubsets function, force.in parameter

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to force in 2 numerical variables into the regsubsets function but the output doesn't show that they are forced in. Is it that it's initially forced-in but there is a better model of n sized parameters that it chooses over the initial model with the forced in parameters?

[image]

[image]

Any reasons as to why G1 doesn't have a star in each model size, even tho I force it in?